# Zlib Calling deflateInit function always returning Z_MEM_ERROR

Tags: zlib

I am using **zlib-1.2.8** and I am calling `compress2(dest, destLen, source, sourceLen, level)` from *compress.c* in my code for compressing the data.

The function `compress2 (dest, destLen, source, sourceLen, level)` is calling 
`deflateInit(&stream, level);`

*deflateInit* is macro.

```
#define deflateInit(strm, level) \
    deflateInit_((strm), (level), ZLIB_VERSION, (int)sizeof(z_stream))
```

That is *compress2* is calling *deflateInit_*.
My Problem is *deflateInit_* is returning `Z_MEM_ERROR`.

I am trying to debug inside *deflateInit_* but not got any debug messages that I have put there.

Also I commented all the exising code inside function *deflateInit_* and return different error from the function ie `Z_BUF_ERROR` but still *deflateInit_* is returning `Z_MEM_ERROR`.
Here if I am explicty returing `Z_BUF_ERROR` still I am `getting Z_MEM_ERROR`.

Please give me some pointers behind this behaviour.

Answer (score 1):

It means what it says.  zlib is calling `malloc()`, which is returning `NULL`.  That is presumably because there is not enough memory availabel to `malloc()` to honor the request.  deflate with the default parameters needs to allocate about 260K to function.

Comment: I am updating zlib library to  zlib-1-2-8 from zlib-1-2-3.
But I am not getting this error with earlier version of zlib. ie zlib-1-2-3. 
Does that mean zlib-1-2-3 allocates lesser memory?

Comment: No.  They allocate the same memory.  What kind of system are you using?  I doubt that in this day of multi-gigabyte RAM you have a system that can't come up with 260K of memory.  There must be something deeper wrong.

Comment: If you are making changes to your zlib but not seeing changes in the behavior, you're probably not running with the zlib that you just built but with some other copy of zlib (libz.so*) that the linker is finding on your computer.  Try using "ldd" to find out.